# how to develop javascript event handle in laravel form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, laravel-5

I need develop form with input text box, radio buttons and optional values in My laravel app.
this is My simple form

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Form Generation</title>
<body>
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br><br>

<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>

<br><br>

<select name="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo XC90</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab 95</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes SLK</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi TT</option>
  </select>

<br><br>

<input type="submit">
</form>


</body>
</head>
</html>
```

I need initial show only input box in My page

```
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
```

and then when cursor select to the input box and enter some values I need show (load) other items of the form

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>

<br><br>

<select name="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo XC90</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab 95</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes SLK</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi TT</option>
  </select>

<br><br>

<input type="submit">
</form>
```

how can I do this?

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Stackoverflow is neither  a free code writing service nor a *"how to"* tutorial service. The objective here is to help you fix **your code** when it doesn't work as expected. See: [ask]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the below one:

```js
$(function(){
$('[name=name]').keyup(function(){
if($(this).val()){
$('div.somename').show();
}
else{
$('div.somename').hide();
}
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br><br>

<div style='display:none'; class='somename'>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>

<br><br>

<select name="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo XC90</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab 95</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes SLK</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi TT</option>
  </select>

<br><br>

<input type="submit">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: This is what you are expecting? @Lilan

Comment: how do I put jquery script in My file? I am new to jquery

Comment: First include jquery library(before form in my answer)..after that paste the jquery content within script like `<script>my jquery content</script>`.

Comment: lalithkumar it is working dear but have some problem here that is when I put some values to the input box it take show other items to click again cursor. but I need show other items just I enter one value to input box @lalithkumar

Comment: glad to help @Lilan